# React Native not able to dispatch action to reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have Problem in dispatching an action and is suppose to update my state in `redux`.

This is my Homepage component. I am able to get the current state of the calculator balance.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { Text, ScrollView, Button } from "react-native";
    import * as reducerActions from "../../store/actions/calculator";
    
    function Homepage() {
      const balance = useSelector((state) => state.calculator.balance);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      console.log(balance);
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>Balance:{balance}</Text>
          <Button
            title="Add to Cart"
            onPress={() => {
              dispatch(reducerActions.DepositMoney(10));
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
    
    export default Homepage;
```

This is my action component: The issue is that it doesn't call my reducer. It logs the value of 10 when I press on the button.

```
    export const DEPOSIT = "DEPOSIT";
    
    export const DepositMoney = (amount) => {
      return { type: DEPOSIT, payload: amount };
    };
```

This is my reducer component:

```
import { DEPOSIT } from "../actions/calculator";

const initialState = {
  balance: 0,
};

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.Type) {
        case DEPOSIT:
          console.log("reducer");
          console.log(action.payload);
          return { balance: state.balance + action.payload };
        case "WITHDRAW":
          return { balance: state.balance - action.payload };
      }
      return state;
    };
```

And this is how i set up the `redux` in my `app.js`

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { AppLoading } from "expo";
    import * as Font from "expo-font";
    import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
    import productsReducer from "./store/reducers/products";
    import ShopNavigator from "./navigation/ShopNavigator";
    import calculatorReducer from "./store/reducers/calculator";
    import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
    
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      products: productsReducer,
      calculator: calculatorReducer,
    });
    
    //composewithdevtools should be taken out for production
    //const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      composeWithDevTools(),
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    );
    
    const fetchFonts = () => {
      return Font.loadAsync({
        "open-sans": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
        "open-sans-bold": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
      });
    };

    export default function App() {
      const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
    
      if (!fontLoaded) {
        return (
          <AppLoading
            startAsync={fetchFonts}
            onFinish={() => {
              setFontLoaded(true);
            }}
          />
        );
      }
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ShopNavigator />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
```

Comment: did you cross check you importing  right action ?

Comment: add console.log(amount) in your action

Comment: Yes it logs the value 10 which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Christian is right but one thing is missing.

> Must copy state before making change in it.

You can also do it like.

```
export default (state = initialState, {type,payload}) => {
      switch (type) {
        case DEPOSIT:
          console.log("reducer");
          console.log(payload);
          return { ...state, balance: state.balance + payload };
        case "WITHDRAW":
          return {...state, balance: state.balance - payload };
      }
      return state;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something silly. The following line was wrong:

```
  switch (action.Type) {
```

It should be:

```
  switch (action.type) {
```